# Do you have a french version?

Tags: wordpress

We are looking for a French version of your app

Answer (score 3):

There is a French translation of CiviCRM available here:
https://civicrm.org/download-translations

There is also a guide to '[Using CiviCRM in your own language](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language)' available.

It doesn't look like the WP demo site lets you change the language to test, but you can do it on the Drupal test site: http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/:  Administer > Localization > Languages